# How to lookup with nested ref in aggregate Mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using $lookup aggregate to join collection but I am facing a problem from the result.
Specifically, I have three collections look like:

**Post:**

```
     id: 1,   
     title: 'my title',
     content: 'bla bla bla',
     ...
```

**Comment:**

```
     post_id: 1,
     user_id: '123',
     content: 'great article!!!',
```

**User:**

```
     id: '123',
     name: 'Ferb'
```

My code to query post and this post also contain comment:

```
        $lookup: {
            from: 'comments',
            localField: 'id',
            foreignField: 'post_id',
            as: 'comments',
        },

        $project: {
           id: 1,
           title: 1,
           content: 1,
           comments: '$comments'
        }

According to the results i got:

           id: 1,
           title: 'my title',
           content: 'bla bla bla',
           comments: [
              post_id: 1,
              user_id: '123', // needs to $lookup from User model
              content: 'great article!!!',
           ]
```

But this is not what I expected, I want to $lookup user_id in comments list with nested $lookup. What should I do to get the expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I am against the idea of nested `$lookup`, as that is likely to reduce the readability of query.

I prefer something simple as `$lookup` twice.

```js
db.posts.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "comments",
      "localField": "id",
      "foreignField": "post_id",
      "as": "commentsLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$commentsLookup"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "commentsLookup.user_id",
      "foreignField": "id",
      "as": "commentsLookup.usersLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$commentsLookup.usersLookup"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      title: {
        $first: "$title"
      },
      content: {
        $first: "$content"
      },
      commentsLookup: {
        $push: "$commentsLookup"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rg7_B19mAhq)

---

However, if you insists in nested `$lookup`, here is one way.

```js
db.posts.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "comments",
      "localField": "id",
      "foreignField": "post_id",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$lookup": {
            "from": "users",
            "localField": "user_id",
            "foreignField": "id",
            "as": "usersLookup"
          }
        },
        {
          "$unwind": "$usersLookup"
        }
      ],
      "as": "commentsLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$commentsLookup"
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4iitiL3166O)

Comment: Thanks, I am very grateful for your help. But in first way, `$commentsLookup` wouldn't return array, example in this case I have multiple comments from comment collection

Comment: The first way `$commentsLookup` should return array

Comment: First way work incorrect for me :(((

Comment: @Epple updated the answer to use `$group` to wrangle back to your expected form